# SQL Join question

Tags: sql

I'm a SQL newbie, so please forgive the ignorance :)

Basically, I'm wondering what would be a good way of 'joining' 2 tables A and B wherein I just want to check if certain cases in A are in B. The thing is, Not all entries in A need to have matches in B, just a few. For example, Table A

```
merchant_id | tablet_id | address
33232       | 1         | 83 abs
94732       | 2         | 92 bcu
47373       | 3         | dkid
48238       | 3         | kdid
```

has joins with other tables in a query. In this same query, I want to implement a condition wherein if tablet_id in B matches with that of A, then to ignore those cases.

```
merchant | tablet_id  | incentive?
33232    | 1          | Yes
67382    | 2          | No
```

Like I said, A and B only have a few cases in common. I tried a query with a JOIN between A & B and got nothing returned since a join might not be possible if there are no intersecting values between A & B. I'm just looking to implement an IF condition kind of thing.

Hopefully I was articulate. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: BTW -- if you're really new to SQL, this is a light-weight tutorial that might give you a few ideas about some of the most basic stuff (joins and such): http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM `A` WHERE `tablet_id` NOT IN (SELECT `tablet_id` FROM `B`)
```

Comment: While the following may not occur in OP's scenario, it is worth noting that this suggested query will not work if table B's tablet_id can contain NULL values. Instead, you would want to use a NOT EXISTS clause that would look similar to "WHERE NOT EXISTS (select 1 from B where B.tablet_id = A.tablet_id)"

Comment: Thanks! I have a follow-up question to this which actually fits my scenario.. what if table_id just had some table_id numbers and the corresponding values were stored in a separate column, say table_value? So, both A has just table_id and B has table_id and table_value. I want to make sure that table_value <> are eliminated from A (although there might not be matches between A & B in certain cases, which is fine).

Comment: @user862449 I'm not quite sure what you mean. Could you edit your original post and add it to the bottom in more detail and let me know when you have?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
   *
FROM 
   A LEFT JOIN B 
     ON A.tablet_id = B.tablet_id 
WHERE 
   B.tablet_id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for the `OUTER JOIN`.

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB ON TableA.tablet_id = TableB.tabletID
```

This will return all rows from table A, and join rows from Table B where they meet the criteria in the ON clause.  If no row exists in Table B for a row in Table A, the Table B column values in the results will be NULL.